# php search printing all items even without inputting any character

Tags: php

This is my search code,it works but when I got to print go even without entering any character. It still searches. Worst, it prints all the items in the database what would I do. Thanks.

```
 if(isset($_GET['search'])) {

$search_value= $_GET['searchbox'];



//$sql="SELECT idemp,sn FROM employee 
//WHERE idemp like '%$search_value%' OR
//sn like '%$search_value%'";

$sql = "select * from employee where (id_no like '%$search_value%' OR sn like '%$search_value%')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "'$result->num_rows' result/s for '$search_value'";
print "<br><br>";
```

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) { ...do search... } else { echo 'no search query'; }`

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection. Always escape the input from `$_GET` (also for `$_POST` / `$_REQUEST`).

Comment: Plus, start accepting answers before posting new ones.

Comment: @Darren Good thing you didn't put in an answer ;-) You wouldn't have seen a green ticky.

Comment: Haha @Fred-ii- I love it! It's one of the simplest issues! I don't need green ticks, I just need your approval ;-) hahaha

Comment: @Darren OP's a bit of a sponge. I don't give answers to those.

Comment: Big headed programmer. i don't need your answer anyway

Comment: not pleasing you dear if you don't want too k bye

Comment: Dude, that's how Stack was built on, to REWARD the people who have so graciously given their FREE time to HELP you. Hire a developer and see how much that will COST you. Ungrateful, you are.

Comment: Whatever you say dude

Comment: @Fred-ii- I accept na ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change your if condition as

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['searchbox'])){
// do search 
}
```

Comment: Just click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows)

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_GET['search'])) will return true because it is set to empty string.

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] )
```

is the condition you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

First check that your getting any string or not, 
Run your query only when you got something.

```
if(isset($_GET['searchbox']) && $_GET['searchbox'] != ''){
    $search_value= $_GET['searchbox'];
    $sql = "select * from employee where (id_no like '%$search_value%' OR sn like '%$search_value%')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "'$result->num_rows' result/s for '$search_value'";
    print "<br><br>";
}
```